# WSO2 ESB: route to specific node

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

I have **WSO2 ESB** and **ELB** instances installed.
When HTTP request comes to ESB, it opens a socket and waits for response.
But if ELB instantiates new ESB, then response can go to ESB #2 (instead of #1) and find that there is no socket connection. 
How would I route response to ESB #1?

---

[EDIT]

I have implemented custom Axis2 transport, which has class `CustomTransportListener`. There is a `List` of opened socket connections, which wait for response. This is the reason why only ESB #1 can handle response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each ESB in the ESB cluster behind the ELB is the same so it would not matter which ESB node in the cluster serves the request. The purpose of the ELB is to automatically balance the load and make it so that the complexities of the cluster is not seen so it does not provide a way to specify an specific node that should receive the response.

It is not possible to send a request to a specific ESB in the cluster through the ELB because the ELB uses an Round Robin algorithm to dispatch request to the ESB cluster so you can not gurantee that a specific ESB node will get the request. In my opinoin do not think it is a good idea to make the ESB's in the same cluster different from each other :).

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question. In my situation each ESB node  differ from another, because in my custom Transport I store incoming socket connections. So if ELB will redirect request to ESB #2 node, there may be no opened socket connections (but it's still opened in ESB #1).